# Is it possible to see who upvoted your question?

Tags: support, voting

I know it's impossible to see who downvoted your question, but I was wondering whether the case for upvoting is different. I'm always soo curious to know who likes my questions! :)

Comment: I upvoted this, just so you know ;)

Comment: @Clive: Joehoe, thanks! Let's agree that one leaves a comment when he/she upvotes this question. Haha ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'Fraid not...

[All voting is anonymous, even to moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-voted-on-your-posts). Only Stack Exchange developers can see who voted on a particular question/answer.